# deinit is not being called. Help me fix this

Tags: swift, deinit

```
class MyClass {
    func greeting() {
        answer += "Hello, World!"
    }
}

class Handler {
    var closure: (() -> Void)?
    let obj = MyClass()
    
    func setupClosure() {
        closure = {
            self.obj.greeting()
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        answer += "Handler is being deinitialized."
    }
}

var answer: String = ""
func handlerDeinitialization() -> String {
    var handler: Handler? = Handler()
    handler!.setupClosure()
    handler!.closure!()
    handler = nil
    return answer
}

print(handlerDeinitialization())
```

My expected answer is "Hellow, World! Handler is being deinitialized." How to fix this? I want to change one line of code only, not the whole one.

Comment: Your handler's closure is not necessarily being deinitialized in the deinit of `Handler`. Closures are reference types - they get deinitialized when the last reference to this closure gets deinitialized. Independently of this little nit-pick, you can set the closure's reference in the object to nil at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite:

```
    closure = { [weak self] in
        if let self = self {
            self.obj.greeting()
        }
    }
```

(Note that I changed more than one line. But my answer is a huge clue towards how to do it by changing just one line.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Honestly, this is a test from CodeSignal. They ask one line of codes to be edited. No more than 1 line.

Comment: Yes, I see how to do that. But I think they want to know if you see how to do it. My answer is a huge clue; if you know some Swift, or are willing to learn, you will be able to follow where it leads.

Answer (score 1):

```
closure = { [unowned self] in
        self.obj.greeting()
}
```

for one line solution

Comment: What are the consequences of removing the condition used in the original answer?

Comment: If you are saying about 

closure = { [weak self] in
        if let self = self {
            self.obj.greeting()
        }
    }

This is the correct answer. But in code signal test they allowed only one line change. So we can use unowned instead of weak. In the case of unowned you don’t need to unwrap the self.